# Next.js 13: Render component as dynamic html element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

for a long time I've used a `Typography` React component that as an optional `as` prop, that let's the consumer of the component specify what HTML element it should render as. `p`, `h1`, `div`, ...

This has worked fine, but after upgrading to Next.js 13 with server components, I'm getting an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <p>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

This is my component, that no longer works:

```
import clsx from "clsx";

interface TypographyProps {
  as?: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap;
  className?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  style?: "heading-1" | "heading-2" | "heading-3" | "heading-4" | "body";
  weight?: "medium" | "semibold";
  onClick?: () => void;
}

export function Typography(props: TypographyProps) {
  const Element = props.as || "p";

  return (
    <Element
      className={clsx(
        {
          "text-4xl md:text-6xl font-display": props.style === "heading-1",
          "text-3xl md:text-5xl  font-display": props.style === "heading-2",
          "text-xl md:text-2xl": props.style === "heading-3",
          "text-lg": props.style === "heading-4",
          "font-medium": props.weight === "medium",
          "font-semibold": props.weight === "semibold",
        },
        props.className,
      )}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Element>
  );
}
```

**Question: Is there a way to achieve the same result with a server component?**

Comment: Are you using the Pages router, or the App router? This error only appears in SSR/SSG situations, which suggests it's probably the Pages router and therefor not using React Server Components at all.

Comment: If you share the usage of `<Typography>` elsewhere in your app where this error is occurring, that may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I am using the app router. The usage is just straight forward in server rendered components.

Comment: Is it possible you have a block-level element inside your `<Typography>` component? This error also occurs when you end up with something like `<p><div /></p>` or `<p><p>...</p></p>` (or in this case, `<Typography><p>...</p></Typography>`)

Comment: @DanOtt Amazing! Looks like you where right. I had a nested Typography inside a Typography. Looks like the error is gone now. :)